# Application_BeginRequest is not being hit

Tags: asp.net, iis, .net-3.5, global-asax

I have a Website that is using .NET 1.1 app pool and then I also have a Virtual Directory within that website that is .NET 3.5. This Virtual Directory's contents are built with Visual Studio 2008 as a separate project.

When testing, everything works fine and all Global.asax events are hit and the app goes through the execution pipe line without any issues. When uploaded to the server with configuration described above, none of the Global.asax events are hit. (I have tested this by creating an Application level variable that I increment on BeginRequest - it's not being set or incremented).

Can anyone give me a clue as to why Global.asax events are not firing for the 3.5 application?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had this issue here, but I have run 3.5 code inside of a 1.1 site as a "plug-in". When doing that I found that I needed to change the AppPool of the site to bet 2.0 and then the 3.5 code worked properly while the 1.1 code continued to work as it did. Could it be that your site in the root folder is loading, and then your code in the sub/virtual folder is being treated as part of that app instead of it's own? What happens if you change the AppPool to 2.0? Also what versions of IIS are you doing this with?